# Работа с ориентированными графами

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, графы, матрицы

Как можно найти все пути для прохождения из одной вершины графа в другую, если граф ориентированный и задан массив вершин, через которые проходить нельзя? Вершины(начальная, конечная и которые нельзя проходить) задаются с клавиатуры, матрица смежности генерируется случайным образом. Все элементы матрицы хранятся в многомерном массиве. Больше интересует даже не реализация, а сама идея поиска, потому что больше всего теории по нахождению кратчайшего пути, а не всех в целом.

Comment: какие ограничения на граф есть? Поиск в глубину вполне решит эту задачу. (за _конечное_ время).

Comment: @pavel, в будущем будут вершины, которые нельзя посещать, а в данном случае хотя бы начать с того, чтобы искать все возможные варианты

Comment: пишите конечную задачу. Потому что не посетить вершину сделать в разы легче чем все пути искать.

Comment: @pavel, изменил

Answer (score 0):

Обычный backtrack-алгоритм (алгоритм просмотра с возвратом). Запрещенным вершинам ставите, скажем, флаг false в булевском массиве. Далее при посещении очередной еще не пройденной вершины проверяете этот флаг и игнорируете вершину, если false (т.е. переходите на следующего еще не пройденного соседа из той вершины откуда пришли и т.п.).